# Show Dialog when Input value changes

Tags: development, javascript, asp.net

I am working on a Sharepoint application Page to Uplaod a File to a document libary. The Upload can take a bit of time so I want to display the waiting for it Dialog. I check if all requiered fields are filled in my Upload Button Click Method and then i want show the Dialog. I just need a way to call a javascript fucntion within my Code behind. I tried a :

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" runat="server" value="" onchange="ManageWaitingDialog()" />
```

and

```
 if (fieldsfilled) 
        {
            hidden.Value = "SHOW";
 }
```

The event does not fire when I change the value of my input.  Any Help is Welcome thanks.

Comment: Why not show a dialog on the button click event itself?

Comment: sorry but i dont understand I want to show a Dialog when a button is clicked

Comment: You want to show a dialog when button is clicked. Then write the function in the button click event. Why are you writing it under hidden field change event?

Comment: the `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose(SP.Res.dialogLoading15);` function is a javascript function the Button Click event is Server Side C# Code

Comment: Server side button also has an `OnClientClick` event which will let you run JavaScript.

Comment: I know but as sad in the question i need to check if all requiered fields are filled with values befor uploading the file. Only if this is true the file will be uploaded and while it is uploading i want to display  the Sharepoint waiting Dialog but OnClientClick will fire immediately

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an event of the hidden field, after setting your hidden field's value in code, in `document.ready` check the hidden field's value and call the function. Since server code runs before client code, this will work.

Comment: Ok I will try it out tomorrow